# Scatterplot with variable X on X axis and Y on Y axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a dataset with variable A (Age) and B (performance). I want to create a scatterplot with variable A on the X axis and B on the Y axis, but Excel is acting all weird with it.

I have approx 120 data entries, and when I select a scatterplot it appears fine at first glance. But, one of the variables is Age. The highest age is 89, yet the graph shows entries as high as 130. Presumably it has coded the X axis by entry number rather than Age. I've tried everything back and forth and I don't understand why Excel won't show a simple XxY graph with Age along the X-axis and performance along the Y-axis.

This shouldn't be difficult, but I have been struggling for an hour without success.

Say the dataset is this:

[image: pic]

I can't imagine it should be hard, but all I can get is this:

[image: pic]

I imagine this occurs because it has not registering Age as the X axis, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

Comment: Funny, I get the following scatter plot (this is in Excel 2010, but it _shouldn't_ be all that different): http://i.imgur.com/AFDnvu4.png

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the numbers are really numbers, not text that looks like numbers. From the screenshot of the dataset, it appears that the last few visible rows have text in column A. The green warning triangle is a giveaway.

To quickly change all text to numbers, select the column, click Data > Text to Columns > next > next > finish.